# Trouble shooting pd.to_timedelta calculation failure

Tags: python, pandas

I have previously used the following conditional statement successfully

```
for RxDat in df2:

       condition = (df['Tdate'] > RxDat - pd.to_timedelta(46, unit="D")) & (df['Tdate'] < RxDat)
```

Now I am getting the following error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'Timedelta'

I have extracted the following data to illustrate the error

`df['Tdate']` contains

```
[Timestamp('2004-08-25 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2004-10-13 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2004-12-13 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2005-02-21 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2005-04-28 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2005-08-24 00:00:00')]
```

`df2['RxDate']` contains

```
[Timestamp('2004-08-20 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2004-08-23 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2004-08-18 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2004-08-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2004-08-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2004-08-13 00:00:00')]
```

I have tried looking at this a few ways and cannot see why I get the error?

Comment: I was trying to assign the date value in df2 to RxDat.  df2 contained one column.  When I assigned the specific column name as suggested it solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If loop by `d2` then `RxDat` are columns names:

```
for RxDat in df2:
```

Use:

```
for RxDat in df2['RxDate']:
```

Non loop solution with broadcasting, output is 2d numpy array:

```
a = df['Tdate'].to_numpy()[:, None]
b = df2['RxDate'].sub(pd.to_timedelta(46, unit="D")).to_numpy()
c = df2['RxDate'].to_numpy()
              
condition = (a > b) & (a < c)
```

Comment: Thanks Should have asked an hour ago.

Comment: @JohnH - What is final expected ouput? I another words whats doing with `condition` ?

Comment: I am using the condition to determine if a test sample was collected during the 46 days prior to RxDate (treatement date for a cow).   I notice that when you refer to variables in the text and "condition" in your comment it is highlighted with grey.  Looks like I am not formatting correctly. Could you please advise how you do this . Thank you for the non loop solution, I will give it a go.  I have several other conditions to include.  The loop is very slow.

Comment: @JohnH - Hmmm, I do some testing and `& (df['Tdate'] < RxDat)` is necessary? Because seems always get `False`s

Comment: @JohnH - Can you try numpy broadcasting solution for improve performance?